# Core Foundation: why LLVM analyzer report that caller doesn't own object created with *Create* function?

Tags: objective-c, core-foundation

According to [The Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) I have created my own "constructor" - `CFStringCreateFromGoString`. It contains "Create" in its name. I expect that if I call `CFStringCreateFromGoString` then I own returned object.

But according to LLVM static analyzer this is not entirely true and in some cases I receive warning `Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller` - see `1.h`. And in other cases where is no warning - see `2.h`.

From `common.h`:

```
CFStringRef CFStringCreateFromGoString(_GoString_ str) {
    return CFStringCreateWithBytes(NULL, (UInt8*)_GoStringPtr(str), (CFIndex)_GoStringLen(str), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, false);
}
```

From `1.h`:

```
CGRect _GetTextLineGeometry(CGContextRef context, _GoString_ str, CTFontRef font) {
    CFStringRef _str = CFStringCreateFromGoString(str);
    CGRect r = GetTextLineGeometry(context, _str, font); // no warning if I remove this line
    CFRelease(_str); // warning here
    return r;
}
```

From `2.h`:

```
CTFontRef _CreateFontFromFile(_GoString_ path, struct FontSpec spec) {
    CFStringRef _path = CFStringCreateFromGoString(path);
    CTFontRef r = CreateFontFromFile(_path, spec);
    CFRelease(_path); // no warning
    return r;
}
```

Can somebody explain the difference between `1.h` and `2.h`?

**Update 0**

Thx matt for comment.
The problem was at `GetTextLineGeometry` - this function by mistake performed `CFRelease(_str)`. Now I have no warnings.
But I don't understand why warning was in `_GetTextLineGeometry` instead of `GetTextLineGeometry`?

Comment: So this is really an issue with GetTextLineGeometry? Can you provide its implementation? Maybe it does something with `_str` that it should not do...?

Comment: Thx @matt , you are right. I have updated post.

Comment: “But I don't understand why warning was in _GetTextLineGeometry instead of GetTextLineGeometry?” Because that was the point of overrelease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name component "Create" does not perform any magic; it is just a matter of convention. So, for that matter, is the concept of "ownership".

So forget about all that and just think about the retain count.

The static analyzer, unlike mere human beings like you and me, can see all your code, and can count. It is counting the retains and releases on this object. When we get to `CFRelease(_str)` in your first example, you have previously released this same object, causing its retain count to drop to zero; so at this point you are performing an overrelease. Thus the static analyzer flags you at this point.

Now let's go back and think about it again from the point of view of "ownership". Only the "owner" of something can release it; that is what "ownership" means. But the static analyzer is perfectly willing to let you transfer ownership, if you know what you're doing. So if you want to "take ownership" by releasing in GetTextLineGeometry, that's fine with the static analyzer. But when when we get to `CFRelease(_str)`, that is a *second* "owner" — and that isn't cricket. Thus, again, the static analyzer flags you *here*.

Comment: I understand about overrelease and that "Create" is just convention. But as far as I know (I have tested before) this static analyzer can more or less follow this convention and show warning in right place. So I'm afraid that I miss something in ownership convention: I think that `_GetTextLineGeometry` is owner, but analyzer thinks that `GetTextLineGeometry` is owner. Who is right?

Comment: Okay, I expanded my explanation to explain in terms of "ownership" as well. _You_ turned GetTextLineGeometry into the owner by putting a release in there. The static analyzer allows that. But you cannot have it _both ways_. The static analyzer doesn't know that you _want_ it both ways until we get to the _second_ release.

Comment: Again, please keep in mind that although I have requested you to do so, you have refused to _show_ GetTextLineGeometry, even though we have established that it is the source of the issue. I don't know why you are so coy about this. But I can only go on what you have been willing to reveal. If you want to know more, show more. I have given as full an answer as I can based on what I see in your question.